# Error copying data into iplimage

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I have the following piece of code:

```
void ViewPlane::colourPixel(const int u, const int v, const Colour c){

    int step = img->widthStep;
    cout << "U: " << u << ", V: " << v << ", step: " << step << "\n";
    cout << "Colour: " << c.r << ", " << c.g << ", " << c.b << "\n";
    cout << "Data: " << v*step+u*3 << ", " << v*step+u*3+1 << ", " << v*step+u*3+2 << "\n";
    cout << "Data: " << data[v*step+u*3] << ", " << data[v*step+u*3+1] << ", " << data[v*step+u*3+2] << "\n";

    //swap colours round as opencv default image is bgr, not rgb
    data[v*step+u*3] = c.b;
    cout << "done it\n";
    data[v*step+u*3+1] = c.g;
    cout << "done it\n";
    data[v*step+u*3+2] = c.r;
    cout <<"done it\n";
}
```

img is an IplImage pointer, and data is

```
data = (uchar *)img->imageData;
```

I am looping through lots of values of u and v (image coordinates) and assigning a colour to each pixel. However the code just stops half way through this pixel when it reaches u = 148.

Printing out the values reveals the green pixel at this point originally contains '*', and is the only one up to that point which does so. Here is a copy of the output:

```
....
U: 146, V: 0, step: -1219934912
Colour: 0, 0, 0
Data: 438, 439, 440
Data: 
done it
done it
done it
U: 147, V: 0, step: -1219934912
Colour: 0, 0, 0
Data: 441, 442, 443
Data: 
done it
done it
done it
U: 148, V: 0, step: -1219934912
Colour: 0, 0, 0
Data: 444, 445, 446
Data: �, *, �
done it
```

So my question is, what does this star mean? And why is it stopping me from assigning data there?

EDIT: The image size is 400x400px

PS: I just tried commenting out the green channel assignment and this error happens again for the red channel further on. This time it held '@' before assignment, so this makes me think it has no bearing on what's going wrong...In that case, what on earth? I'm not out of bounds of the array, the value I'm inserting is an integer 0...

Comment: Ah..sorry bout that, didn't know I had to!

Comment: You don't "have to", it just helps out others.

Comment: I'd be more worried about step being "-1219934912" than about a star character. It makes it look like you have a stray `img` pointer.

Comment: You are right Pablo, cheers! Now how on earth do I accept that? :p

Comment: @user1135488 posted it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your program's output shows step being "-1219934912". It makes it look like you have a stray `img` pointer. It's rather strange that each line in image would take ~1GB